# Graph represenation logic from array

Tags: php, arrays, string, google-visualization

Array output generated from database values.

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [seldate] => 2019-04-28 [count] => 268 ) 
        [1] => Array ( [seldate] => 2019-04-29 [count] => 366 ) 
        [2] => Array ( [seldate] => 2019-04-30 [count] => 85 ) 
        [3] => Array ( [seldate] => 2019-04-28 [count] => 93 ) 
        [4] => Array ( [seldate] => 2019-04-29 [count] => 82 ) 
        [5] => Array ( [seldate] => 2019-04-30 [count] => 31 ) 
        [6] => Array ( [seldate] => 2019-04-28 [count] => 44 ) 
        [7] => Array ( [seldate] => 2019-04-29 [count] => 44 ) 
        [8] => Array ( [seldate] => 2019-04-30 [count] => 22 ) )
```

I need to create below 
string output from above array for google LineChart.

```
"['2019-04-28',  268, 93, 44],
['2019-04-29',  366, 82, 44],
['2019-04-30',  85, 31, 22]"
```

Please help to create PHP Code logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First prepare your array as key being the date and the values being the values.
Then loop it again and write the lines to a new array with the imploded values.

Lastly output the lines with implode on comma and new line.

```
foreach($rows as $r){
    $dates[$r['seldate']][] = $r['count'];
}

foreach($dates as $date => $vals){
    $lines[] = "['" . $date . "', " . implode(", ", $vals) . "]";
}

echo implode(",\n", $lines);
```

Output:

```
['2019-04-28', 268, 93],
['2019-04-29', 366],
['2019-04-30', 85]
```

https://3v4l.org/14smE

Answer (score 0):

You can traverse array by using [array_walk](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php) as below

```
$result = [];
array_walk($arr, function($item) use(&$result){
    if(empty($result[$item['seldate']])){ // if empty add date and count for initialisation
        $result[$item['seldate']] = [$item['seldate'], $item['count']]; 
    }else{
        $result[$item['seldate']][] = $item['count'];   // just append value to same key as date as we are grouping it by date
    }
});
$result = array_values($result); // to remove date keys
print_r($result);
```

**Output**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2019-04-28
            [1] => 268
            [2] => 93
            [3] => 44
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2019-04-29
            [1] => 366
            [2] => 82
            [3] => 44
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2019-04-30
            [1] => 85
            [2] => 31
            [3] => 22
        )

)
```

[Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ca589fd52c8fc95c45172b0fb1ef764203f5dfe5)

**Note**: If you want to use this data for linechart, [json_encode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) above output.

Comment: I believe it's an actual string output OP needs as it's going to a JavaScript chart.

Comment: I added required note to make OP understand the same